# Checking if in-app subscriptions is active in my serverless android app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I have the serverless android app with simple functional: if user has some in-app subscription (auto renewable), then he can use functional in app, otherwise there is no. I know, how to make functional with obtaining subscriptions info (price, title etc) and calling payment. But I can not check if current user has active (not cancelled) subscriptions. I read so many information on many sites and tutorials, and there was written that I must use google API in my server. But I do not have my own server. 
I used two different libraries for in-app subscriptions:

```
'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
```

and

```
'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
```

but no one helped me for checking if user has active subscriptions. So, how to make this task? Help me please, maybe I missed some information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****Edit:** Anjlab library hasn't been updated in the longest time ever. Kindly use Google's own billing library, this step-by-step process should help you easily integrate it into your app - [Google In App Billing library](https://adapty.io/blog/how-to-integrate-the-google-play-billing-library-into-your-app)**

Using the [anjlab in-app-billing library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) I was also facing the similar. This is what I did to get around it.

Invoke the method `billingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();` Then check the value of transactionDetails, if the `TransactionDetails` object return null it means, that the user did not subscribe or cancelled their subscription, otherwise they are still subscribed.

```
void checkIfUserIsSusbcribed(){
  Boolean purchaseResult = billingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
  if(purchaseResult){
     TransactionDetails subscriptionTransactionDetails = billingProcessor.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails(YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);

     if(subscriptionTransactionDetails!=null)
        //User is still subscribed
     else  
        //Not subscribed
     }
}
```

Also, point to note is that the `TransactionDetails` object will only return null after the period of the subscription has expired.

Comment: will this method return false for canceled Transactions or Retained Transactions?

Comment: how can i get the expire date?

Comment: The funny thing is nobody knows if that library uses version 3 or older. If older, then after November 2021 you are screwed. And surprisingly there is not a single solid tutorial on version 3 or 4 either on google docs, or YouTube, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to call `bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();` ?

**Edit**

So try this :

```
Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(product);
Log.d(TAG, "Purchase state: " + purchase.getPurchaseState());
// 0 (purchased), 1 (canceled), or 2 (refunded).
if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == 0
     || purchase.getPurchaseState() == 2) {
   showPremiumVersion();
} else {
   showFreeVersion();
}
```

Or this solution :

```
bp.isPurchased("yourSKU")
```

Comment: Of memory, it's a async task so you need to wait before check the new value

Comment: hm, i cannt find method inventory.getPurchase(). Is it in library anjlab or com.android.billingclient:billing ?

Comment: @AlexD. it's anjlab but i was using this in a old version, try bp.isPurchased("yourSKU")

Comment: method isPurchased(id) always returns false (because i work with subscriptions only). And method isSubscribed(id) returns true after i subscribed, but when i cancel the subscription and it expire time ends, method isSubscribed returns always true too, and this is error. So i dont know how to solve this problem :(

Comment: have you try to wait 48h ? It's can be long. And i'm almost sure that `bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();` is working, just try to wait 48h.

Comment: its very bad, because testing with waiting in 2 days is very bad and uncomfortable option

Comment: It's like publish an app, you don't really have the choice

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as @filol.. And my subscription was expired (canceled) like months ago. But isSubscribed() always returns true. Did anybody find a solution for this?

Comment: will this method " isPurchased(id) " work after user reset his phone and reinstalled this app??

Answer (score 0):

The isPurchsed method can't catch history of error's purchase / canceled Purchase/ Retrived Purchase.

Use this and don't forget to add INTERNET permission in your manifest.

```
TransactionDetails transactionDetails = billingProcessor.getPurchaseTransactionDetails("productId");
 if (transactionDetails != null) {
     //Already purchased
     //You may save this as boolean in the SharedPreferences.
 }
```